Multiple monitors rearrange after sleep
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 now but had the same issue on 22.04 and other intermediate non LTS versions.
I have a Desktop PC with a NVidia GeForce 1060 running three monitors. One is a 55" Samsung 4k display and the other two are sceptre 21" 1080P monitors. The two Sceptre monitors are stacked on top of one another, to the left of the Samsung.
When the system cold boots, everything is as it should be, but when the system wakes up from sleep, the monitors ae all rearranged into a line, the Samsung goes to 1080P and the two sceptres mirror each other. I have to shut down and reboot to get it all right again.
Any input on what I can do to get the display settings to stick?

Are the models the same make and model?  If not, they are likely enumerating out of sequence and it is being applied in sequence.
Ubuntu SHOULD still remember it and auto correct but maybe that code isn't in it.
Did you try it with 24.04?
